# php fopen: Authentication Error: Access Denied, Wrong authentication protocol

Tags: php, authentication, fopen, mjpeg

i like to read an mjpeg stream with php to chunk one jpg-image out of the stream. The stream will be created from my webcam. The webcam is password protected.

This is my code:

```
function mjpeg2jpg_convert(){
$camurl="http://admin:secretpass@192.168.1.60/Streaming/Channels/1/httppreview";

$boundary="\n--";

$f = fopen($camurl,"r") ;


   if(!$f)
   {
        //**** cannot open
        echo "error";
   }else{
    $cnt = 0;    
    //**** URL OK
    $r = "";
    $l = "";
         while (substr_count($r,"Content-Length") != 2 && $cnt<10000){
            $l.=fread($f,512);
            echo $l;
            $r.=$l;
            $cnt++;
         }

         $start = strpos($r,'ÿ');
         $end   = strpos($r,$boundary,$start)-1;
         $frame = substr("$r",$start,$end - $start);
echo "FRAME";
         //header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
         echo $frame;
   }
fclose($f);
}
```

The result is:

> Access Error: 401 -- Unauthorized
>
> Authentication Error: Access Denied, Wrong authentication protocol.

If i copy the url in my browser ie or firefox, the stream will be loaded without any errors. So the username and password is correct.

Maybe some of you have an idea.

Maybe there is also a ready to use code to get the first jpg out of an mjpg stream in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the any solution of this?